# This routine does not work in protect mode

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Intersect(Target, Range("A1:J10"))
If Not rg Is Nothing And Range("V7") = "YES" Then
[RowNo] = ActiveCell.Row
[ColNo] = ActiveCell.Column

End If
End Sub
```

…

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("V7")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target = "NO" Then [AK1:AL1] = 0
End If
End Sub
```

The above SelectionChange does not work when the sheet is in protect mode. Is there any way to correct this. In protect mode it hangs up on the line that says [RowNo] = ActiveCell.Row. This works correctly when sheet is unprotected.

Comment: In your code, unprotect the sheet, update the cells, then re-protect the sheet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649347/unprotect-sheet-workbook

Comment: @Tim Williams, I have tried that before. Does get inserted inside of the subroutine or outside of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
'...
Me.Unprotect                  'in a sheet module Me=the sheet
[RowNo] = ActiveCell.Row
[ColNo] = ActiveCell.Column
Me.Protect
'...
```

Comment: thanks that solved the problem to make it run, but the drawback on that is the numbers I needed to remain locked are now unlocked, but I don't intend to use that routine the whole time, just for a quick check to find numbers. I have seen the word "Me" and wondered what it was used for. Now I know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unless you unlock the cells before you re-protect the sheet they should be protected again  once your code is done.